# Full Install of Kali to usb - grub-install returns error

Tags: usb, grub, kali-linux, grub2

I have tried to install Kali Linux on an USB drive according to [this article](https://myguide.fyi/books/os-install-guides/page/how-to-full-install-of-kali-linux-on-usb-with-luks-encryption-and-uefi#bkmrk-%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0-%23-fixing-%2F-re).
I'm stuck at the 5th step.

When I run this command:

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=kali-grub --boot-directory=/boot --removable --recheck --debug
```

It returns the error of:

```
grub-install: Error: /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/modinfo.sh doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory
```

I have applied some solutions that I found, but the command doesn't run successfully.

How can I solve the problem?